# SVN Error: could not commit files to svn

Tags: svn, phpmyadmin, apache2, zend-studio

I have checked out a working copy from SVN using Zend editor. I cant commit the changes to SVN. Its throwing an error 
[Some of selected resources were not committed.
 svn: Commit failed (details follow):
 svn: can not read HTTP status line
 svn: CHECKOUT request failed on '/project/!svn/bln/1798']

All other functions are working properly like update, Comparing with repository.
Once I have removed 'phpmyadmin'and re-installed apache2 then 'commit' works for some days and same problem repeats.

Comment: I dont know why mysql is tagged, please remove it

Comment: Do command-line SVN operations work successfully?

Comment: No its also not working. Commit operation fails all the time

Comment: svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: CHECKOUT of '/project/!svn/vcc/default': Could not read status line: connection was closed by server (http://subversion.project.com)

Answer (score 0):

Try "Update" you project after you see this error.
P.S. in Eclipse - Project - Team - Update, it's helpful.

Comment: I have tried out that also 'Update' is working fine. Problem is only when Committing and it happens only in my PC also.

Comment: Committing is not working both before and after Update. I have created a new working copy, changed one file and tried to commit then also file fails to commit.

Comment: Maybe http communication problem between SVN Client and SVN repository, make shure that you enter the correct URL and you have permission for accessing project directory. Does the log of the HTTP server show any HTTP error?

Comment: Previous time when the same error occurs i have restarted apache2 then it was working fine for some days. So is there any possibility that the reason behind this is an internal system error?

Comment: Thanks XCK, you realy helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was due to Ethernet connection. Particular Ethernet gateway connection blocks the committing of file to staging. Changing the ethernet gateway solved the problem.